# how to type ajax correctly?

Tags: ajax

i know how to use one form data use ajax:

```
$.ajax({
       type:'get',
       url:'blabla.php',
       data:$('#abc').serialize();
       .........
```

but how if i want to type:

```
$('#exportmod').click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                            "dataType":'json',
                            "type":'GET',
                            "url":'shows_merchan.php',
                            "data": [ action:"searchmodelqp",
                                      jhead:"aaData",
                                      month:$("#search_month").val(),
                                      year:$("#search_year").val(),
                                      export:"excel"
                                    ],
                             "success":function(json){
                                                       fnCallback(json);
                                                       }
                             });
                    });
```

could you show me the correct type for this ajax?

Comment: That looks about right, is it erroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, just the bracing on your `data` is wrong, it should be `{}` rather than `[]` for an object, like this:

```
$('#exportmod').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'shows_merchan.php',
     data: { action: "searchmodelqp",
             jhead: "aaData",
             month: $("#search_month").val(),
             year: $("#search_year").val(),
             export: "excel"
           },
     success: fnCallback
   });
});
```

The other change above show what you *can* do.  You don't have to quote identifiers for words that aren't reserved (as long as their valid...and all the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) options are), also there's no need for an anonymous wrapped to call a function with the same signature, so I changed `success` to use your callback directly.

There's also a shortcut for the above [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call, [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$('#exportmod').click(function(){
  $.getJSON('shows_merchan.php', 
            { action: "searchmodelqp",
              jhead: "aaData",
              month: $("#search_month").val(),
              year: $("#search_year").val(),
              export: "excel" }, 
            fnCallback);
});
```

Comment: @klox - See on `data`? `[]` notes an array literal, not an object literal...so it's just not valid formatting.  You want an object here, which ultimately get passed to `$.param()` to be serialized as your querystring.